# Modify existing htaccess rewrites to not match particular URLs

Tags: htaccess, url-rewriting, regex

Trying to rewrite only particular URL's, for example:-

(1) I want to rewrite:-

```
http://www.example.com/keyword-1
http://www.example.com/keyword-1/sub-keyword
http://www.example.com/keyword-1/?p=50
```

(2) I don't want to rewrite:-

```
http://www.example.com/keyword-1-product
```

This is what I have so far...

```
RewriteRule ^/?alfred-victoria$             /brands/alfred-victoria/ [R=301,L] 
RewriteRule ^/?alfred-victoria/(.*)$       /brands/alfred-victoria/ [R=301,L]
```

These handle (1) above but not (2), URL's that start with the keyword in `/alfred-victoria-blah-blah` are also getting rewritten.

How can I modify the rules above to exclude these URL's. I thought the dollar ($) indicated end of string and ignore anything else after this point?

Comment: As you suggest, neither of those two rules can be redirecting `/alfred-victoria-blah-blah`. So, either there is _something else_ that is performing this redirect, or a previous (erroneous) 301 redirect has been cached - clear the browser cache etc. Also, confirm whether this is a 301 redirect and not a 302 or some other 3xx (could help indicate where this is happening).

Comment: Hmm, yes, seems you were right, looks like it was cached. Should have tested in incognito before asking the question. Hah - Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you suggest, neither of those two rules can be redirecting `/alfred-victoria-blah-blah`. So, either there is something else that is performing this redirect, or a previous (erroneous) 301 redirect has been cached - clear the browser cache etc.

Also, confirm whether this is a 301 redirect and not a 302 or some other 3xx (could help indicate where this is happening).

It would seem that an old redirect was cached on this occasion.